# What is the meaning of git push message

Tags: git

Whenever I push my changes to a remote git repository, I see the following message:

```
git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 289 bytes | 289.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
To https://github.com/username/repo.git
   ec9080f..7456e61  master -> master
```

My question is, what does the above block of text mean?

Specifically, what are `objects`, `Delta compression`, `threads`, `reused 0 (delta 0)`, `resolving deltas`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-push%5D+delta+compression+threads+reused